# Como fazer o os value do input apareça no json?

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

então estou com duvida aqui, seria possível fazer com que os campos input que tenho jogue o que digitei em um JSON?

EX:  este seria o formulario

```
        <form role="form" method="post" id="searches" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/form.php" novalidate >

                <label class="input-da-serach-1" for="de">De <input type="text" id="de" name="de" placeholder="Cidade:" required ></label>

                <label class="input-da-serach-1" for="searches=[to_airports]">Para <input type="text" id="searches=[to_airports]" name="searches=[to_airports]" placeholder="Cidade:" required ></label>

                <label class="input-da-serach-2" for="date_go">Ida <input type="date"  name="go_date" min_days="1" max_days="365" required></label>

                <label class="input-da-serach-2" for="data_back">Volta (opcional)<input type="date" name="search[back_date]" min_days="1" max_days="365" ></label>

                <label class="input-da-serach-2">Passageiros <input type="text" name="" placeholder="01" ></label>

                <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Procurar">Procurar</button>

            </form>
```

ele teria que pegar os value digitados no -> (de) -> (para)

e jogar no JSON

```
class MCrypt
{
  private $key;
  public function __construct($token) {
    $this->key = $token;
  }

  function crypt($message, $url_encode = true) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted) .'|'. base64_encode($iv);
    if ($url_encode) return urlencode($encrypted);
    else return $encrypted;
  }
  function encrypt($message, $url_encode = true) {
    return $this->crypt($message, $url_encode);
  }
  function decrypt($encrypted_message, $url_decode = true) {
    if ($url_decode) $tokens = urldecode(trim($encrypted_message));
    else $tokens = trim($encrypted_message);
    $tokens = explode('|', $tokens);
    if (count($tokens) == 2) {
      $crypt = base64_decode($tokens[0]);
      $iv = base64_decode($tokens[1]);
      $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
      echo preg_replace('[x00-x1Fx80-xFF]', '', $decrypted);      
    }
    else return false;
  }
}

$url = "******";
$crypt = new MCrypt('*********');

$encrypted_data = $crypt->encrypt('

{"searches":
["amigo", "multiplus", "tudo_azul"],
"type":"award_flight_money_tax",
"includes":"none",
"from_airports":"**jogar o valor do de aqui**",
"to_airports":"**jogar o valor do para aqui**",
"go_date":"2018-03-22",
"go_date_flexibility":"0",
"back_date":"2018-03-28",
"back_date_flexibility":"0",
"adults":"1",
"children":"0",
"babies":"0",
"cabin":"E"
}');

?>

urls: <?php 

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"data={$encrypted_data}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo ($output);

 ?>
```

o local esta em negrito que deve pegar o valor do input e jogar no local indicado, desde já agradeço..

tentei muitas coisas mas sempre da erro, e estou sendo obrigado a usar este método sem pode alterar esta área.

```
{"searches":
["amigo", "multiplus", "tudo_azul"],
"type":"award_flight_money_tax",
"includes":"none",
"from_airports":"**jogar o valor do de aqui**",
"to_airports":"**jogar o valor do para aqui**",
"go_date":"2018-03-22",
"go_date_flexibility":"0",
"back_date":"2018-03-28",
"back_date_flexibility":"0",
"adults":"1",
"children":"0",
"babies":"0",
"cabin":"E"
}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, recupere o valor dos campos com o método POST.

`$de = $_POST['de'];`
`$para = $_POST['para'];`

Em seguida, decodifique o "texto" do json com a função `json_decode`

`$decode = json_decode($string_com_o_json, true);`
O parâmetro "true" converte a string em array associativo.

Em seguida, você pode substituir o valor da chave "from_airports" e "to_airports", definindo-as novamente:

`$decode['from_airports'] = $de;
$decode['to_airports'] = $para;`

Depois, transformar a variável já alterada em json novamente:

`$decode = json_encode($decode);`

E em seguida, utilizar a variável $decode do jeito que preferir.
Espero ter sido útil e claro.

Comment: vou tentar e posto aqui o resultado

Comment: não deu certo, =(

Answer (score -1):

Consegui! Após esclarecimentos do @Haroldo Torres, mudei algumas coisas.

Segue o código pronto para se um dia alguém aparecer com a mesma duvida.

Essa área vai pegar seus *inputs*

```
$de = $_POST['de']; 
$para = $_POST['para'];
$date_in = $_POST['date_in'];
$date_out = $_POST['date_out'];

$decode = json_decode($string_com_o_json, true);
```

Aqui você vai criar um *json* a ser exibido

```
$decode['searches'] = "amigo";
$decode['type'] = "award_flight_money_tax";
$decode['includes'] = "none";
$decode['from_airports'] = $de;
$decode['to_airports'] = $para;
$decode['go_date'] = $date_in ;
$decode['go_date_flexibility'] = "0";
$decode['back_date'] = $date_out ;
$decode['back_date_flexibility'] = "0";
$decode['adults'] = "1";
$decode['children'] = "0";
$decode['babies'] = "0";
$decode['Cabin'] = "E";

$decode = json_encode($decode);
```

Aqui ele faz o show do *json* depois da codificação por um todo

```
$encrypted_data = $crypt->encrypt ( $decode );
```

> Obs: os locais onde não tem o `$` na mostragem do *json* e o que é por padrão do formulário e você não quer que o *input* do formulário o altere.

Espero ter explicado bem.